# Android - Image glitches and loaded to another item(which has null or empty image from api) in recycler view when scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-glide, android-paging-3

I am trying to load api data with Paging 3 library (with coroutines) and it was successfully loaded and displayed in a recycler view. The problem is - The items having image url showing the image (using Glide) and those having null or empty image url shows the placeholder instead. But when i scroll down and again scroll to up Images messed up. The items having null image url also showing the images from other positions .

Suppose , having a list of 100 items. In which 30 items having images and other having null.
When I scroll many times down and up  and. ....so on , All items in the recycler view will show the images.

I also tested in the normal way - Having just calls the api with retrofit and in response body(), I update the data in adapter without any library (Mvvm, coroutines etc ), the older way. But the result remains the same.

```
 Glide.with(context)
.load(rideData.driver.image_with_url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
.circleCrop()
.into(imgMovie)
```

- 

Can someone help me!*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it can be caching problem, if the url is null the problem occurs. You can solve it in compile time by adding placeholder to your imageView src, and if the url is not null it will replace it with your url on runtime:

```
            <ImageView
                ...
                android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />
```

But that method can cause you to see the placeholder first and replace with the url in the time of loading the app. Instead you can check if the url is null and if it is null set its source to your placeholder image. Avoid using glide's placeholder.

```
if (yourUrl != null) {
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(rideData.driver.image_with_url)
         .circleCrop()
         .into(imgMovie) 
} else {
    Glide.with(context)
         .load(R.drawable.placeholder)
         .circleCrop()
         .into(imgMovie) 
}
```